# How to rename theorem (or lemma) in Beamer to another language?

Tags: beamer, theorems, naming

I'm Malay user. I want to rename the theorem tag in Beamer. Does anyone know how to do it? When the document class is article or book, I can simply modify the preamble as follows:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Korolari}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Bukti]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
```

However, the above things does not work in Beamer. So, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 36):

`beamer` uses `translator` to translate environment names and some other words. It uses 
some `.dict` files which you can translate to your language and start to use. Look at manual's section `Translating strings`. Here you have a little example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\uselanguage{spanish}
\languagepath{spanish}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Theorem}{Teorema}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{theorem}{teorema}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
I will translate \structure{\translate[to=spanish]{theorem}} but not theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `\begin{block}{Korolari} ... \end{block}`.

Update: A better and more detailed explanation can be found in [Beamer newtheorem translation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201972/1952)

Comment: I tried to use `\deftranslation` with Danish, which did not just work. The problem was that I needed to spell Danish with a capital D. E.g.
`\deftranslation[to=Danish]{Theorem}{Sætning}`.

Comment: Using `\uselanguage{Spanish}` and `\languagepath{Spanish}` will automatically load translations -- observe the upper case!

Answer (score 10):

`beamer` already provides theorem environments: `theorem`, `corollary`, `definition`, `definitions`, `fact`, `example`, `examples`, and `lemma`. You can disable them by a class option, then you can define your own environments without those name conflicts. For `proof` use `\renewenvironment`, as it's also predefined.

So you could use `beamer` environments if you would like to benefit from `beamer` features, using `beamer`'s syntax, or define your own with numbering and formatting as you like.

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Korolari}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Bukti]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
```