# Beamer newtheorem translation

Tags: beamer, theorems

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\uselanguage{Spanish}
\languagepath{Spanish}

\deftranslation[to=Spanish]{Proposition}{Proposición}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{proposition}
    Foo
  \end{proposition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will print the Proposition environment as `Proposition` and I want it printed as `Proposición`. I know I can define the new environment as `\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposición}` but I was wondering if the translation can be done automatically i.e if the language of the document is `spanish` and a new theorem environment is defined as `\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}` then print the word `Proposition` in spanish.

Comment: I think you need to define something like `\propositionname` in the same way that `babel` sets up things like `\bibname`. That is, you need a language-sensitive macro to trigger `babel`'s magic.

Comment: @cfr I do want to trigger babel's magic. In the article class I define a general new theorem in English and when babel switches language the theorem environment name switches accordingly. I want to achieve the same thing in beamer class

Comment: One difference maybe that `beamer` uses its own translation-setup. That is, it does not use `babel`. If you look at `beamerbasemisc.sty`, you can find a note to the effect that the translation stuff is 'suboptimal' and that `babel` should be used (but isn't). So for `beamer`, you might need to look at the way `beamer` does it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following likely won't work in the real world so you'll have to try it and see. However, it does at least produce the right result for the MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\uselanguage{Spanish}
\languagepath{Spanish}

\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{\translate{Proposition}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{proposition}
    Foo
  \end{proposition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: A Spanish proposition]

Answer (score 10):

As it has been already explained, `Beamer` uses `translator` (its particular `babel` system). If the `dictionary` exists, you can active the system introducing the language name in `beamer` options: `\documentclass[spanish]{beamer}`. This way `spanish` is applied to `beamer-translator` system and `babel`. If `spanish` is passed only as `babel` option, you need to apply it for `beamer` with `\uselanguage{spanish}\languagepath{spanish}`.

So with an example like:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{proposition}
    Foo
  \end{proposition}

  \begin{theorem}
   Foo2
   \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

you'll get

[image]

As you can see, `theorem` is translated but `proposition` is not. Why? Because theorem, corollary, fact, lemma, problem, solution, definition and example environments are already provided by `beamer` but not `proposition`. And how are all these environments declared? Take a look at `beamerbasetheorems.sty`

```
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{\translate{Corollary}}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{\translate{Fact}}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{\translate{Lemma}}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{\translate{Problem}}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{\translate{Solution}}
```

All of them make explicit use of `translate` command as cfr suggested in his answer. You can do the same:

```
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{\translate{Proposition}}
```

There's no need for `\deftranslation` because `proposition`is already defined in `translator`dictionarys.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation! I apologize for accepting the other answers but I only did that because he answered first.

Comment: @Ignasi. Usefull answer. However, it is nice for beamer, but it doesn't work in article class. How you can add to the dictionary the word **Propiedad**, where `\deftranslation` dosen't work?

Comment: @Ignasi. Don't worry for my previous comment. The solution to my problem is use the `translator` package. It seems `beamer`uses it automatically.

Comment: Please fix the following: the correct spelling is `beamerbasetheorems.sty` .

Comment: @Ignasi How can I do the same for "definition" environment so the text is not in italics?