# Changing theorem naming while preserving numbering in Beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems

I want to change the name of theorems in `beamer`, from the preset "Theorem" into "Teorema", while preserving its numbering order alongside with definitions and lemmas. At present I use the code

`\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]`.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename theorem (or lemma) in Beamer to another language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38392/how-to-rename-theorem-or-lemma-in-beamer-to-another-language)

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

I have used `newtheorem` macro `\newtheorem{thm}{\translate{Teorema}}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{thm}{\translate{Teorema}}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{thm}
This is a sample Teorema.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer!